# Outside Access via IPv6 and DSLite

Tags: networking, ipv6, dynamic-dns

I am using Vodafone Germany, which provides IPv4 & IPv6.

IPv4 is provided via DS-Lite Tunnel.

I have also set up DuckDNS (Dynamic DNS) for a raspberry in my network. Let's say my hostname is `mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org` and it has no IPv4 and it has only AAAA entry `2a02:908:......`

Also, I want to reach my port `8123`, so when I hit up my browser, it gets rejected (even when using another network). `wget` output is this:

```
wget http://mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org:8123
--2022-03-17 10:38:42--  http://mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org:8123/
Auflösen des Hostnamens mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org (mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org)… 2a02:908:......
Verbindungsaufbau zu mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org (mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org)|2a02:908:......|:8123 … fehlgeschlagen: Connection refused.
```

When entering the IPv6 directly in the browser, everything works:

`http://[2a02:908:......]:8123`

Needless to say, I opened port 8123 for IPv6 and that specific device.

How can I achieve that my connection succeeds when entering `http://mycoolraspberry.duckdns.org:8123` in the browser?

EDIT: When using `ping6` on that hostname it says: `ping6: getaddrinfo -- nodename nor servname provided, or not known`, but a check on `mxtoolbox.com` for the AAAA record shows the correct IPv6.

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly the same address in both cases? (And specifically is it the Pi's own address, not the router's?) Are you trying to `ping6` just the hostname, or are you also trying to include "http://"? Can `nslookup` or `host` resolve the hostname? Have you tried flushing the DNS cache in your OS?

Comment: Hey @user1686 those are all good suggestions.

To answer a few: I ping6 with the hostname, not http:// in front, of course. 
I also flushed the DNS Cache. nslookup only resolves the IPv4, not IPv6. 
And yes, i have separate dyn dns running for different devices, so my PI has his own IPv6.

Comment: But if you say there's only an AAAA record, then what do you actually mean by "nslookup only resolves the IPv4"?